# Optimize nested Loop java

Tags: java, networking, compare, ip-address

I have a requirement where the loop is slowing down. Is there a better way to write or optimize this code.

**Background**

It's related to IP Address. Out of a supernet. The user wants to create subnets. However, some subnets could already be created. Those created subnets and networks falling under them should not be shown. 
*e.g.* 10.0.0.0/23 is the supernet. 10.0.0.0/24 is already created. Now the function should only show 10.0.1.0/24 and hide 10.0.0.0/24.
I have written the code but its very slow.

**Code**

This function compares two IPAddress Arraylists. One is the already created subnets in DB and other is the total possible networks that could be created. If any of the networks falls in any defined network range. It is removed from all networks list.

*newPrefix* is the user entered prefix for new subnets.
*existingSubs* is an ArrayList already created within this Supernet.
*newSubs* Is the ArrayList of all possible networks using newPrefix in that supernet.

```
for (IPAddress exSub : existingSubs) {
  if (exSub.getNetworkPrefixLength() < newPrefix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < newSubs.size(); i++) {
      IPAddress newSub = newSubs.get(i);
      if (exSub.contains(newSub)) {
          newSubs.remove(newSub);
          i--;
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (int i = 0; i < newSubs.size(); i++) {
      IPAddress newSub = newSubs.get(i);
      if (newSub.contains(exSub)) {
        newSubs.remove(newSub);
        i--;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using [this](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/v2/#_Toc456708513) library

Comment: Rather than an array, couldn't you use a hash list?

Comment: I tried HashSet. It was even slower

Comment: I meant something like a dictionary. That should be much faster than looping through a large array, looking for something that may not exist.

Comment: Hi have partially solved it. I converted all the existing subnets to the new prefix and then removed those from newSubs list. Its working a lot better now